# OpenCV : Add/merge/combine 'only part' of Image A to Image B

Tags: java, python, c++, opencv, image-processing

I have checked out some already answered questions regarding adding(combining/merging) two images with`OpenCV`. But my question is a bit different here. I want to **add/merge/combine *only some part* of image A to image B**. Consider the example below :-

[image]

In this picture, `Image A` - guy wearing spectacles

`Image B` - guy without spectacles (Mr. Bean)
So, what I am looking for is some `algorithm` or function in `OpenCV`, by which I can make `Image B` having *only spectacles* of `Image A` (**that is, merging part of `Image A` into `Image B`**.) (Also, please not - I don't want my result to look like `Image C` here which is morphed version of both images. I just want to add spectacles from `Image A` to `Image B`. Rest everything will be as it is in `Image B`)
Any help is highly appreciated :)

In my case, programming language doesn't matter. I can work with any language C++, Java, python, Ruby etc.
If you still didn"t understood my query, I can explain again.
Looking forward to some good solution. Thanks

Comment: You need to segment spectacles first. Then just use `copyTo` with the segmentation mask.

Comment: Thanks @Miki for the reply. Yes segmentation is one good option. But, segmentation might not work properly, if my Image B is not properly aligned or have side angle like this image - http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-imSsKoyz9Ss/VfpcPPp78aI/AAAAAAAAA1I/EcOQ9y7QPNU/s1600/Mr_bean-smart.jpg   So, I was thinking more of a generic approach like remodelling of repainting Image B again dynamically based of Image B 's angles or alignments. Is something like this possible?

Comment: To do that you need 3D model of both spectacles and face

Comment: and can we recreate 3D model of the Image A and B from their 2D version ?

Answer (score 1):

Your questions is not very clear - you don't specify exactly what you know about the input images.

Assuming that you somehow identify the regions to cut in both images (and this is the hard part), then it becomes a trivial compositing procedure. The basic algorithm uses a "matte", i.e. an black/white image of the same size as the original one, white in the first image's (background) areas to keep, and black elsewhere. You multiply the first image by the matte, and the second one by the matte's negative, and you sum the results.

Comment: Thanks Franceso . And if both images are not of the same size, in that case will your method work or I will have to first resize images to the same size and then apply matte on them?

Comment: and if both images (which we want to merge) are not at same orientation (or alignment) ,  3.bp.blogspot.com/-imSsKoyz9Ss/VfpcPPp78aI/AAAAAAAAA1I/ like this one and Image A above , then how can I merge spectacles with this image ? Miki said about needing 3D models of both images, but is it possible to render 3D images from their 2D images?

Comment: Yours is not a SO question any longer.