# OpenCV image stitching and stitching associated csv files

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

Firstly, I would like to state I am new to computer vision and OpenCV. I am still learning the basics, but have a question for the future of my project. Currently, my project contains a set of images and CSV files holding particular information about the pixels in those images. The images I have are 512x640 and the csv files have 512x640 cells of information. I have used ORB detection and descriptors in order to find interest points and used a BF matcher in order to map them. Following guides online, I have used the ratio test to find "good" points and then `cv2.warpPerspective()` function to stitching them together. Now I, very lightly, understand homography is also added in this stage to figure out orientation. The output image will be larger than the inputs. Now my question is whether there is a way to find what coordinates are actually discarded in this process. By this I mean is there a way to find the coordinates from the original image that are actually visible in the stitched one. If the final stitched image is 1000x1000px I want to create a 1000x1000 csv with valid points from the three original images. I would love to know if this is possible, and if so maybe some sort of explinaton on concepts I should persue in order to solve this issue.

Further Example: I have 3 images 512x640. In a perfect example the stitched image will be 512x(640*3) This means no overlap so it would be easy to fetch the pixel values from the csv since they are 1 to 1. Now if the image is not as such, meaning 512x1000 how do I create a new csv file with 512*1000 that holds the values of what is visible in the stitched image. Ignore the coordinates that have overlapped.

Comment: you want to join three 512x640 px image?

Comment: So the problem is we have the face of a building split up into 2 or more images. I want to stitch these together to produce a face BUT also according to the stitched images fetch values from my CSV files that correlate to what is visible on the stitched image. Does that make sense? I'm sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I think that if you have the images correctly labeled in your dataset you could access to his position and get the pixels of them to merge all them in one new image array. Check this I hope helps you: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/01/11/opencv-panorama-stitching/  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33318229/opencv-add-merge-combine-only-part-of-image-a-to-image-b